# How do I retrive a js script built by php using ajax and have the script run?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps

I am using google maps API to build my own world.
The problem I am running in to is that the data number of markers/locations cause the page to become unresponsive.

So I believe; and could be wrong; that the solution is to call only the markers/location that are with in the bounds(that is to say visible on the window) and at the zoom level.

I was thinking that if i get the bounds of the window and zoom level and pass that to a php script that would build the js marker function and then call that function.

However i have tried a rudimentary scripts that looks like it returns the function but it does not activate the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadDoc() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("script").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                       eval(this.responseText);
                   }
               };
               xhttp.open("GET", "fjack.php", true);
               xhttp.send();
           }
       </script>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="loadDoc();"> click </div>
    <div id="script"></div>
    <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the php script:

```
<?php
    echo "<script>";
    echo "function me(){
              document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML=\"ITS WORKING\";  
   } 
   me();";
   echo "</script>";
?>
```

I have tried eval() but that did nothing.

Comment: Now you are only pasting your code into your site. There is no trigger to activate it.

Comment: u can achive this without ajax like <script src="yourphpscript.php?ifanyparam=0">

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score -1):

You're almost there, just return .js code from the server without `<script>` tags and evaluate the string using eval, so you'll have to change this:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("script").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                       eval(this.responseText);
                   }
```

with this:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                       eval(this.responseText);
                    return;
                   }
```

and the server(php script) response looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "function me(){
              console.log('hello world!'); 
   } 
   me();";
```

It works but using eval() is not the best choise; I recommend to use a function object for this(new Function('dynamic content -server response here')) or even better, a js module loader, which check your module's dependencies and dinamically loads the required js files in the right order, in the header section, using `<script>` tags, no need for XHR requests, as it was already mentioned in a previous reply to your question. Take a look at http://requirejs.org